# Is it correct to say "mammals became the dominant species"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it correct to write this:

> After the dinosaurs went extinct, mammals became the dominant species.

Since mammals/Mammalia is a "class", is it more correct to say:

> After the dinosaurs went extinct, mammals became the dominant class.

I worry readers will be completely confused by the meaning.

Or is the fact mammals is plural allow me to use "species"?

Comment: Drop the whole thing and just say, ”… mammals became dominant”

Comment: I think either is fine, if you’re writing for a lay audience, who aren’t very concerned about the nitty gritty of taxonomy. That said, “dominant”, huh? I think the beetles, bugs, and bacteria would like a word with you…

Comment: Grammar aside, is this factually correct? How are you defining 'dominant', exactly?  I think you could make a case that beetles are the dominant animal lifeform.

Comment: @Pete - I think on ELU if we offer help we should limit it to help formulating English sentences to say what the OP wants to say and stay away from debating whether what they want to say is true or not.

Comment: @Pete Sea-going *Pelagibacter ubique* notwithstanding, it's at best true amongst terrestrial quadrupeds only, unless they're talking about humans. Dinosaurs didn't go extinct, either. [The fossil record shows that birds are modern feathered dinosaurs, having evolved from earlier theropods during the Late Jurassic epoch, and are the only dinosaur lineage to survive the Cretaceous–Paleogene extinction event approximately 66 million years ago.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur)

Answer (score 1):

You could say "mammalian species became dominant". But you don't need to. 'Species' as a plural agrees with 'mammals'. Some audiences may disagree for technical or factual reasons, but they won't be confused.

Answer (score 1):

Gold star for finding a situation where a noun with identical plural and singular forms rescues a biology error. But "dominant species" seems to be a familiar phrase, even in this misapplication (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominant_Species).

Readers who are confused by the phrase "dominant class," as a phrase: likely few.

Readers who are confused by the phrase "dominant species," as a phrase: likely few.

Readers who read "mammals became the dominant species," are concerned by their existing knowledge that they are in fact a class, but are reassured upon remembering that "species" is also plural: **likely few**.

Also, a footnote: although interpreting "species" as a plural is a clever way of rescuing the grammaticality, it might be factually incorrect. "Mammals became the dominant class" is not the same thing as "Some or all of the mammalian species became the dominant species in their ecosystem."